# Код не связанный с циклом замедляет его

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6

Я столкнулся с необычной ситуацией. Строка кода, добавленная перед циклом и никак с ним не связанная, замедляет выполнение цикла. Вот как это выглядит в "уменьшенном виде".

У меня есть метод с примитивным циклом:

```cs
int[] array = new int[ElemCnt];

public int Sum()
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        sum += array[i];

    return sum;
}
```

Этот метод модифицируется затем следующим образом:

```cs
long state = 1;

public int Sum2()
{
    int sum = 0;

    if (Interlocked.Read(ref state) == 0)
        return sum;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        sum += array[i];

    return sum;
}
```

т.е. просто добавляется проверка перед циклом.

Логично предположить, что время выполнения этой проверки можно оценить некой константой. Время выполнения второго метода (при худшем исходе) тогда можно оценить как `T2 ≈ T + C`, где `T` - время выполнения первого метода, а `C` - время выполнения проверки (CPU считаем не загружен). С ростом длины массива следует ожидать, очевидно, что время выполнения двух методов будет всё менее различимым (`T2 ≈ T`).

Такого, однако, не происходит:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19044.1766 (21H2)
Intel Core i5-4690 CPU 3.50GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 4 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.301
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.6 (6.0.622.26707), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.6 (6.0.622.26707), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | ElemCnt | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sum | 1000 | 590.1 ns | 6.22 ns | 5.81 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| Sum2 | 1000 | 1,896.4 ns | 9.88 ns | 9.24 ns | 3.21 | 0.03 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sum | 10000 | 5,729.5 ns | 27.40 ns | 24.29 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| Sum2 | 10000 | 18,929.2 ns | 208.10 ns | 194.66 ns | 3.30 | 0.03 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sum | 100000 | 57,273.8 ns | 258.89 ns | 242.17 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| Sum2 | 100000 | 187,707.1 ns | 2,121.93 ns | 1,984.85 ns | 3.28 | 0.03 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sum | 1000000 | 590,207.1 ns | 9,395.29 ns | 8,328.68 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| Sum2 | 1000000 | 1,943,186.9 ns | 34,793.55 ns | 32,545.90 ns | 3.29 | 0.06 |

т.е. в действительности получается `T2 ≈ K * T`!

Это наводит на мысль о том, что во втором случае цикл выполняется медленнее. Будто бы добавленная проверка каким-то образом замедляет цикл. В чём здесь дело?

---

Код бенчмарка:

```cs
public class LoopBench
{
    int[] array = null;
    long state = 1;

    [Params(1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)]
    public int ElemCnt { get; set; }

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        array = new int[ElemCnt];
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public int Sum()
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            sum += array[i];

        return sum;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int Sum2()
    {
        int sum = 0;

        if (Interlocked.Read(ref this.state) == 0)
            return sum;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            sum += array[i];

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> В чём здесь дело?

Если сравнивать IL-код двух методов, то ничего криминального не просматривается.

Вот так выглядит IL второго метода:

```
.maxstack  3
.locals init (int32 V_0, int32 V_1)
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0001:  stloc.0
IL_0002:  ldarg.0
IL_0003:  ldflda     int64 LoopBench::state
IL_0008:  call       int64 Interlocked::Read(int64&)
IL_000d:  brtrue.s   IL_0011
IL_000f:  ldloc.0
IL_0010:  ret
IL_0011:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0012:  stloc.1
IL_0013:  br.s       IL_0024
IL_0015:  ldloc.0
IL_0016:  ldarg.0
IL_0017:  ldfld      int32[] LoopBench::'array'
IL_001c:  ldloc.1
IL_001d:  ldelem.i4
IL_001e:  add
IL_001f:  stloc.0
IL_0020:  ldloc.1
IL_0021:  ldc.i4.1
IL_0022:  add
IL_0023:  stloc.1
IL_0024:  ldloc.1
IL_0025:  ldarg.0
IL_0026:  ldfld      int32[] LoopBench::'array'
IL_002b:  ldlen
IL_002c:  conv.i4
IL_002d:  blt.s      IL_0015
IL_002f:  ldloc.0
IL_0030:  ret
```

Для первого метода IL-код я не привожу, т.к. он практически идентичен и выглядит так, как если бы из кода второго метода выкинули инструкции с *IL_0002* по *IL_0010* (собственно проверка и возврат). Что касается цикла, и в особенности тела цикла (с *IL_0015* по *IL_002d*) - различия отсутствуют.

А вот JIT генерирует немного разный код. И в теле цикла как раз таки есть отличия.

Код первого метода, если выкинуть всё второстепенное, выглядит так:

```
; LoopBench.Sum()
       sub       rsp,28
       xor       eax,eax                        // sum = 0
       xor       edx,edx                        // i = 0
       ...
M00_L00:
       ...
       movsxd    r9,edx                 
       add       eax,[r8+r9*4+10]               // sum += array[i]
       inc       edx                            // i++
       cmp       [rcx+8],edx
       jg        short M00_L00                  // array.Length > i
M00_L01:
       add       rsp,28
       ret
```

А код второго метода (также без второстепенных деталей) - так:

```
; LoopBench.Sum2()
       sub       rsp,28
       xor       eax,eax                        // sum = 0
       mov       [rsp+24],eax                   // [stack] <- sum
       ...
M00_L00:
       xor       eax,eax                        // i = 0
       ...
M00_L01:
       ...
       movsxd    r8,eax
       mov       r9d,[rsp+24]                   // sum <- [stack]
       add       r9d,[rcx+r8*4+10]              // sum += array[i]
       inc       eax                            // i++
       cmp       [rdx+8],eax
       jg        short M00_L03                  // array.Length > i
M00_L02:
       mov       eax,r9d                        // return sum
       add       rsp,28
       ret
M00_L03:
       mov       [rsp+24],r9d                   // [stack] <- sum
       jmp       short M00_L01
```

Главное отличие заключается в том, что во втором случае **на каждой итерации цикла** накопленная сумма загружается из стека в регистр (*r9d*) и после суммирования сохраняется обратно в стек. В первом же случае сумма накапливается сразу в регистр (*eax*) и в стек не попадает вообще. Именно эта дополнительная работа со стеком (вкупе с тем, что обращение к памяти медленнее, чем к регистрам процессора - даже с учётом возможного кэширования) и вызывает падение производительности во втором методе.

Работа со стеком не сказывалась бы заметно, если бы в цикле было много работы. Но здесь её очень мало. Поэтому такая код-генерация выглядит скорее нетипично, т.к. циклам с небольшим телом (их детекции и оптимизации) компилятор уделяет особое внимание.

> Будто бы добавленная проверка каким-то образом замедляет цикл

Нет, сама проверка не замедляет выполнение цикла. Но её присутствие заставляет JIT генерировать для цикла менее производительный код.

Такое поведение RyuJIT компилятора - регрессия от предыдущих версий:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19044.1766 (21H2)
Intel Core i5-4690 CPU 3.50GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 4 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.301
  [Host]             : .NET 6.0.6 (6.0.622.26707), X64 RyuJIT
  .NET 6.0           : .NET 6.0.6 (6.0.622.26707), X64 RyuJIT
  .NET 5.0           : .NET 5.0.17 (5.0.1722.21314), X64 RyuJIT
  .NET Core 3.1      : .NET Core 3.1.26 (CoreCLR 4.700.22.26002, CoreFX 4.700.22.26801), X64 RyuJIT
  .NET Core 2.2      : .NET Core 2.2.8 (CoreCLR 4.6.28207.03, CoreFX 4.6.28208.02), X64 RyuJIT
  .NET Framework 4.8 : .NET Framework 4.8 (4.8.4515.0), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | Runtime | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sum | .NET 6.0 | 587,219.9 ns | 11,480.13 ns | 10,738.52 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| Sum2 | .NET 6.0 | 1,943,794.5 ns | 15,662.22 ns | 13,078.66 ns | 3.33 | 0.04 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sum | .NET 5.0 | 584,441.7 ns | 9,659.41 ns | 9,035.41 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| Sum2 | .NET 5.0 | 1,955,357.4 ns | 18,500.14 ns | 16,399.89 ns | 3.35 | 0.06 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sum | .NET Core 3.1 | 597,269.8 ns | 8,984.42 ns | 8,404.03 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| Sum2 | .NET Core 3.1 | 1,987,871.5 ns | 35,514.92 ns | 33,220.67 ns | 3.33 | 0.09 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sum | .NET Core 2.2 | 585,353.0 ns | 7,527.64 ns | 7,041.36 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| Sum2 | .NET Core 2.2 | 576,804.1 ns | 2,975.21 ns | 2,637.45 ns | 0.99 | 0.01 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sum | .NET Framework 4.8 | 580,485.7 ns | 5,634.76 ns | 5,270.76 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 |
| Sum2 | .NET Framework 4.8 | 591,283.8 ns | 8,772.34 ns | 8,205.65 ns | 1.02 | 0.02 |

В *.NET Framework 4.8* и *.NET Core 2.2* всё было ещё не так плохо :)

О проблеме я [сообщил](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/71628) "куда следует". Возможно она будет исправлена в будущих версиях *.NET*.

Comment: Закинуть бы это на гитхаб мелкомягким

Comment: Очень интересно! / В статьях наподобие [Performance Improvements in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/) мелкомягкие прямо пишут, что хотя новые версии языка/рантайма в среднем быстрее, но иногда приходится идти на регресс в целях секурности и т. п.

Comment: На гитхаб я уже закинул. Возможно пофиксят в net-8. Но ссылку я вставлю позже, чтобы не спойлерить ещё один забавный момент, на который наткнулся пока с этим разбирался.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, здесь всё же несовершенство компилятора, т.к. если чуть-чуть переписать (эквивалентно), то код-генерация будет нормальный. Самое отвратительное, что расследование таких случаев требует несвойственных компетенций. Но тем же это и интересно. Кстати, назначивший на себя эту проблему человек написал [Loop alignment in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/loop-alignment-in-net-6/). Познавательная тоже статья (возможно читали).