# Странная проверка для this

Tags: c#, .net, ассемблер, .net-6, jit

Разбираясь с [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1427600/193999) проблемой, я заметил одну деталь в коде, который генерировал JIT для "модифицированного" метода. Рассмотрим упрощённый вариант.

Пусть есть класс:

```cs
public class ThisCheck
{
    long state = 0L;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void Foo() => Bar(ref this.state);

    //[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static void Bar(ref long value) => value++;
}
```

Далее для экземпляра класса вызывается метод *Foo*:

```cs
var inst = new ThisCheck();
inst.Foo();
```

В режиме Release компилятор делает подстановку *Bar* в *Foo*, соответственно для *Foo* генерируется вот такой код:

```
; ThisCheck.Foo()
       add         rcx, 8                    // rcx <- ref this.state
       inc         qword ptr [rcx]           // this.state++
       ret
```

Если запретить подстановку (раскомментировав строку), то код для *Foo* и *Bar* выглядит так:

```
; ThisCheck.Foo()
       sub         rsp, 28h
       cmp         dword ptr [rcx], ecx
       add         rcx, 8                    // rcx <- ref this.state
       call        ThisCheck:Bar(byref)      // Bar(ref this.state)
       nop
       add         rsp, 28h
       ret

; ThisCheck.Bar()
       inc         qword ptr [rcx]           // value++
       ret
```

По сути то же самое, но перед вызовом *Bar* внутри *Foo* появляется инструкция:

```
cmp         dword ptr [rcx], ecx
```

При входе в метод в регистре *ecx* стандартно размещается *this*. Соответственно в `[rcx]` лежит ссылка на таблицу методов класса. Какой смысл сравнивать ссылку на экземпляр класса со ссылкой на таблицу методов класса? Причём результат сравнения далее по коду не используется.

Что это за странная проверка?

Answer (score 7):

> Какой смысл сравнивать ссылку на экземпляр класса со ссылкой на таблицу методов класса? Причём результат сравнения далее по коду не используется. Что это за странная проверка?

В .NET Runtime таким образом реализована проверка ссылки на *null*. Вот как это работает:

- адрес экземпляра класса и адрес таблицы методов класса для любой действительной ссылки на экземпляр естественно никогда не совпадают; сравнение выполняется, выставляя соответствующие флаги в регистре флагов, и исполнение инструкций благополучно продолжается; использование результата сравнения не требуется
- если же ссылка содержит *null*, то происходит попытка обращения к памяти по нулевому адресу; это вызывает исключение, которое среда выполнения соответствующим образом обрабатывает, генерируя *NullReferenceException*

Таким образом (хотя в это и трудно поверить), компилятор в данном случае добавляет проверку *this* на *null* перед вызовом *Bar* (точнее - перед обращением к `this.state`). Приблизительно как если бы в C# мы написали:

```cs
public void Foo()
{
    if (this == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    Bar(ref this.state);
}
```

То есть проверка сама по себе не странная, но видеть её для *this* действительно странно.

---

Появление этой проверки можно проследить в дампе компиляции.

Вот так выглядит HIR (*High-level Internal Representation* - высокоуровневое внутреннее представление) для вызова *Bar* внутри *Foo* после импорта IL-кода:

```
[000003] --CXG-------              ▌  CALL      void   ThisCheck.Bar
[000002] ---XG------- arg0         └──▌  ADDR      byref
[000001] ---XG--N----                 └──▌  FIELD     long   state
[000000] ------------                    └──▌  LCL_VAR   ref    V00 this
```

И вот этот же фрагмент после морфинга:

```
[000003] --CXG+------              ▌  CALL      void   ThisCheck.Bar
[000010] ---XG+-N---- arg0 in rcx  └──▌  COMMA     byref
[000006] ---X-+-N----                 ├──▌  NULLCHECK byte
[000005] -----+------                 │  └──▌  LCL_VAR   ref    V00 this
[000009] -----+------                 └──▌  ADD       byref
[000007] -----+------                    ├──▌  LCL_VAR   ref    V00 this
[000008] -----+------                    └──▌  CNS_INT   long   8 field offset Fseq[state]
```

Видно как видоизменяется передаваемое в *Bar* в качестве аргумента выражение. Вместо `ref V00.state` появляется узел `COMMA` (*[000010]*) с двумя дочерними узлами (`NULLCHECK V00` и `V00+8`). Узлы этого типа используются, чтобы, когда это возможно, с меньшими затратами вставить код в середину оператора (не разбивая его на несколько). Для `COMMA` результат первого дочернего узла будет отброшен после выполнения, а результат выполнения второго вернётся в качестве результата выражения.

Узел *[000006]* во время морфинга появляется вот с таким пояснением:

```
Morphing args for 3.CALL:
...
GenTreeNode creates assertion:
[000006] ---X---N----              ▌  NULLCHECK byte
In BB01 New Local Constant Assertion: V00 != null, index = #01
...
```

т.е. как контроль значения переменной *V00* (фактически `this != null`).

Далее, после преобразования HIR в LIR (*Low-level Internal Representation* - низкоуровневое внутреннее представление) и некоторых других преобразований, в фазе генерации машинного кода получаем:

```
Generating: N005  [000005] ------------         t5 =    LCL_VAR   ref    V00 this         rcx REG rcx
                                                              ┌──▌  t5     ref
Generating: N007  [000006] ---X---N----              ▌  NULLCHECK int    REG NA
IN0001:        cmp      dword ptr [rcx], ecx
Generating: N009  [000007] ------------         t7 =    LCL_VAR   ref    V00 this         rcx (last use) REG rcx
Generating: N011  [000008] -c----------         t8 =    CNS_INT   long   8 field offset Fseq[state] REG NA
                                                              ┌──▌  t7     ref
                                                              ├──▌  t8     long
Generating: N013  [000009] ------------         t9 = ▌  ADD       byref  REG rcx
IN0002:        add      rcx, 8
                                                              ┌──▌  t9     byref
Generating: N015  [000015] ------------        t15 = ▌  PUTARG_REG byref  REG rcx
                                                              ┌──▌  t15    byref  arg0 in rcx
Generating: N017  [000003] --CXG-------              ▌  CALL      void   ThisCheck.Bar REG NA
IN0003:        call     ThisCheck:Bar(byref)
```

Таким образом, инструкция *cmp* появляется именно как реализация `NULLCHECK` контроля для *this*.